DC power supply
I tested a bench power supply on a linear actuator I have, and set to 24V. It seems to draw from 400-600ma, going up to around 800ma when under load (me pushing against it). I set to CC 600ma and while it wasn't great, it still worked. So from this, I deduced that I could buy a 24V 1A DC supply.
So... soon as I soldered the new supply I bought, all the actuator does it briefly move slightly every second before switching off and on again, stuttering each second and not moving much while I hold down the buttons for either forward or reverse.
So from this, I'm thinking that numbers of voltage and amps are not the full story when using a bench supply to determine what power supply to buy? I know they are usually only about 80% efficient, but I though 1A would have been enough to cover this? It was a cheap e-bay supply with really thin wires, so maybe this is the issue, or am I missing something about switch mode power?

I could be that it sucks more current during startup/transient behavior and the new one is not able to supply that. How much current could your first power supply deliver?

you might have some luck with adding a cap in parallel to the PSU output, say 1000-3300uf.

Might give that a try, good suggestion

While the actuator might average around 600-800mA, motors and linear actuators often draw a higher inrush current at startup or during load changes (e.g., when reversing or encountering resistance). This could be several times the steady-state current.
A 1A power supply might not be able to provide the short bursts of higher current needed, causing the voltage to drop and triggering the supply's overcurrent protection, leading to the stuttering behavior.
You should dimension your Power supply ~2-5x the rated current for your application if you buy those cheap supplies and expect to drive an application where you expect inrush currents. Those cheap supplies are simply not good at transient response.
Also cut out the thin wires. The voltage drop aross the thin wires may have been the tipping point for your supply to fail.

2-5x as much? Wow. Thanks for the guide, I will buy a 5A supply I think
